# Basic confusion about $Tor_n$ and projective resolutions

Tags: homological-algebra

Osborne's text has the below basic example.

### 1. Example 9

$R = \mathbb Z_4$, $A = B = \mathbb Z_2$ A projective resolution of $\mathbb Z_2$ is

$$ \cdots \rightarrow \mathbb Z_4 \xrightarrow{\times 2} \mathbb Z_4 \xrightarrow{\times 2} \mathbb Z_4 \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb Z_2 \rightarrow 0 $$

Tensoring with $\mathbb Z_2$ and deleting gives
$$ \cdots \rightarrow \mathbb Z_2 \xrightarrow 0 \mathbb Z_2 \xrightarrow 0 \mathbb Z_2 \rightarrow \cdots $$

So that $Tor_n^R \cong \mathbb Z_2$ for all $n$.

### 2. Not a projective resolution of $\mathbb Z_2$?

But now consider the projective resolution
$$ \cdots \xrightarrow{0} 0 \xrightarrow{0} 0 \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{\times 2} \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb Z_2 \rightarrow 0 $$

Tensoring with $\mathbb Z_2$ and deleting
$$\cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb Z_2 \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb Z_2 \rightarrow 0$$

So now we have $Tor_n^R(A,B) = Z_2$ for $n = 0, 1$ but $Tor_n^R(A,B) = 0$ for $n \ge 2$. What did I get wrong here?

### 3. Similar issue in the case where $R = \mathbb Z_8$, $A = B = \mathbb Z_4$

Proceeding in the same way as above, I get $Tor_n^R(A,B) = Z_4$ for $n = 0, 1$ but $Tor_n^R(A,B) = 0$ for $n \ge 2$

### 4. Osborne's definition of $Tor$.

I believe this definition is standard, but just in case provide it below.
[image]

Comment: In point 2 you wrote a projective resolution of abelian groups, not of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-modules

Comment: @IDC: can you elaborate? Isn't $\mathbb Z$ a left $\mathbb Z_4$ module? Can't we regard $\overline 2 \mathbb Z$ as the kernel of $\pi$?

Comment: It's not. How would you multiply an integer by an integer modulo 4 and get an integer?

Comment: Thanks! I think I see a resolution now.